# Exchange Transaction Schema - Database Design

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, nosql, relational-database

I'm trying to develop a commodity based exchange platform that Implements all type of Transactions

**Scenario**

1.We have a Commodity, Say gold for example, with prices in different currencies

2.Each User could have multiple wallet for storing their Commodity

```
{
"userId":"1",
"wallets":
          [
           {"walletName":"goldwallet1", "commodityId":"1", "walletAddress":"7x000abcd"},
           {"walletName":"goldwallet2", "commodityId":"1", "walletAddress":"7x111efgh"},
           {"walletName":"coinwallet3", "commodityId":"2", "walletAddress":"7x222efgh"},
          ]
}
```

2.This Commodity (Gold), Can be Buy from / Sell to Our Platform with different currencies like EUR, USD and store in User Wallet

3.Beside Buy/Sell Transactions, There are 4  Type of transaction that must be Implemented.

**One)** *Withdraw*: User Can Withdraw their commodity or the equivalent price at this moment and receive it from our store with a Tracking-Number

**Two)** *Transfer*: User Can Send/Receive Commodity To/From their wallet address

**Three)** *Exchange*: User Can Exchange one Commodity to other types

**Four)** *Pay(Spend)*: User Can spend their commodity to buy a service or a product...

---

For this problem I came up using this approach:

1.One Big Transaction Table with 5 inherited table

```
Transaction
  Id
  WalletId
  Amount(Sign)
  Type(Buy/Sell/Withdraw/Exchange/Pay)
  CreatedAt


Pay
  TransactionId
  For(ProductId)

Transfer
  TransactionId
  To/FromWalletId:
  Type:(Send/Receive)

Exchange
  TransactionId
  DestinationWalletId
  CommodityId
  ExchangeRate

Withdraw
  TransactionId
  Traking-Number
```

I'm going to use SQL Server Express for beginning but I'm even in doubt if the RDBMS is good for this scenario or should I consider No-SQL...

Comment: IMO you have just stated your data analysis and it is premature to decide on a schema or an dbms engine. Assuming this isn't some trivial student project, you have significant work ahead to flesh out your systems capabilities. However, "recording transactions" is mostly a trivial function. Making use of and sense of that recorded information is what will drive your design. Commodities trading is a very complex business - you have much work and learning ahead. Trading in multiple currencies is also very **very** complicated.

Comment: @SMor Well thanks, As you mention that this isn't a student project and I have to decide many side effect in near future...I made some modification but it still need many improvement...Thanks btw.

Comment: What did you decide with your design?

Comment: @SarvarNishonboyev I finally came up with what I explained here and it does almost fit well but for the buy/sell transactions you need extra work.

Comment: @MehrdadKamali I'm working on an eWallet project and it seems similar to your design. I think in my case Buy represents Topup, Sell is payout (to the bank account). If I'm wrong, how do you topup your wallet in your system? Can you also share the scheme for buy/sell type pls? Cheers!

Comment: @MehrdadKamali Also, what DB have you used? I'm thinking to use RDMBS because of atomicity.

Comment: @SarvarNishonboyev Buy and sell entities represent very differently from deposit and withdrawal entities in an exchange platform. so I think you don't need to bother yourself to designing those schemas.
I used SQL Server and Postgre. Yes, when we're talking about transactional data the best solution is still the RDBMS family.

Comment: @SarvarNishonboyev Consider deposit (topup) and withdrawal (payout) higher-level transaction in oop manner that has some more properties which identify the full transaction.

Comment: @MehrdadKamali Cheers. One more question what is Traking-Number in Withdraw table?

Comment: @MehrdadKamali I can see you have a separate table for each type. Do you have also a separate table for the deposit?

Comment: @SarvarNishonboyev Sorry for not getting back to you sooner. tracking-number is third parties unique transaction id when the user deposits/withdraws from/to other sources. (for example, tracking number in cryptocurrency would be transaction hash)

Comment: @SarvarNishonboyev Yes TPT (table-per-type) is what I used to design this schema.